# How do you to Add The Contents of Two TextBoxes Together and Display in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm dynamically create two textboxes and a textblock. The user first clicks a button which adds a row of controls and then inputs numbers in each textbox. The sum of the two boxes for a given row will be displayed in a text block.

Here is the XAML.

```
    <Window x:Class="ModelBuilder_080614.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModelBuilder_080614"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.DataContext>
            <!-- this is a comment -->
            <local:MainWindowViewModel />
        </Window.DataContext>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Canvas.Top="21" Canvas.Left="20" Content="Add TextBox" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
            <ItemsControl  Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"   Name="Bench" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding <!-- I'm LOST -->}"/>
<!-- I want this TextBlock to sum the Two TextBlocks -->
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Canvas>
    </Window>
```

And here is my Model and ViewModel in C#.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using MicroMvvm;

namespace ModelBuilder_080614
{

    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> SomeCollection { get; set; }

        public ICommand TestCommand { get; private set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            TestCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CommandMethod);
        }

        private void CommandMethod(object parameter)
        {
            SomeCollection.Add(new Model());
        }
    }

    public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        double _actual;
        double _bench;
        double _active;

        public double Actual
        {
            get { return _actual; }
            set { _actual = value; }
        }

        public double Bench
        {
            get { return _bench; }
            set { _bench = value; }
        }

        public double Active
        {
            get { return _active; }
            set { _active = Actual - Bench; }

        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do you bind the contents of the textboxes to display the sum of them  in the TextBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the properties in your ViewModel: *(I removed the grid settings to make the example clearer)*

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Actual, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Bench, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Active" />
```

Then when your values change, raise the notification on the "Active" property so it updates. You only need a "getter" on the "Active" property... when you call `OnPropertyChanged()`, it will perform the calculation and update the field for you.

```
double _actual;
double _bench;

public double Actual
{
    get { return _actual; }
    set
    {
        _actual = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Active");
    }
}

public double Bench
{
    get { return _bench; }
    set
    {
        _bench = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Active");
    }
}

public double Active
{
    get { return Actual - Bench; }
}
```